# Fetching revolution slider shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying something new here. I have a Wordpress custom theme. I have Advanced custom fields all setup. I'm using the advanced custom field's load_field function on a "select" field with "choices". What I want to basically do is to show the revolution slider shortcodes as choices for this field... This is my code in the functions.php file. Any help would be highly appreciated! :)

```
<?php

function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {

    $field['choices'] = array(
        <-- WANT REVOLUTION SLIDER SHORTCODES HERE -->
    );

    return $field;

}


// all
// add_filter('acf/load_field', 'my_acf_load_field');

// type
add_filter('acf/load_field/type=select', 'my_acf_load_field');

// name
// add_filter('acf/load_field/name=my_select', 'my_acf_load_field');

// key
// add_filter('acf/load_field/key=field_508a263b40457', 'my_acf_load_field');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is the following. Revolution slider slider items are stored in a table called wp_revslider_sliders (the wp_ part may change based on how you set up the database - check the table name first)

You can query this table using the Wordpress ***$wpdb*** global and get back the alias field - which is used as the shortcode. So in the body of your load field function you could try something like this

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = sprintf('select r.id, r.alias from %srevslider_sliders r',$wpdb->prefix);
    $sliders = $wpdb->get_results($query,OBJECT);

    foreach($sliders as $slider)
    {
        //This just formats the string with the correct short code
        $field['choices'][$slider->alias] = sprintf('[rev_slider alias="%s"]',$slider->alias);
    }

    return $field;
}
```

That should populate your dropdown with the right options - or at least get you on the right path

Comment: No problem - happy to help out. Can you mark the answer as correct so that anyone else searching for the answer knows that there's a solution?

Comment: You should not assume the table prefix is "wp_". Use ```$wpdb->prefix```

Answer (score 4):

**Answer updated April 22, 2020: For Slider Revolution V6, the function `getAllSliderAliases()` has been replaced with `get_sliders()` and returns an array of objects instead of an array of strings.** [Source](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/developer-guide-get-all-slider-alias/).

**functions.php for Slider Revolution V6**

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'RevSlider' ) ) {
        $rev_slider = new RevSlider();
        $sliders = $rev_slider->get_sliders();
        if(count($sliders) > 0) {
            foreach($sliders as $slider)
            {
                $field['choices'][$slider->alias] = $slider->title;
            }
        } else {
            $field['choices'] = array( 'none' => 'No sliders exist. You must create one first.' );
        }
    } else {
        $field['choices'] = array( 'none' => 'Slider Revolution plugin was not found.' );
    }
    return $field;
}
//Only place these options on a specific select field with the alias "rev_slider"
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=rev_slider', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

And then on the template or whatever page you're using the custom field on, I placed the actual shortcode there instead.

**page.php**

```
$slider_alias = get_field('rev_slider');
if(!empty($slider_alias)) {
    echo do_shortcode(sprintf('[rev_slider alias="%s"]', $slider_alias));
}
```

---

**Old Answer for versions of Slider Revolution before V6**

For whatever reason, my `$sliders` variable from Andrew M's answer wasn't returning anything, so I came up with this solution instead based on [Themepunch's documentation](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/show-a-random-slider-on-any-given-page/) for displaying any slider at random and [this article](https://eric.blog/2016/04/11/get-a-list-of-all-revolution-sliders-aliases/) for checking if the class exists first to avoid errors.

**functions.php for Slider Revolution versions before V6**

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'RevSlider' ) ) {
        $rev_slider = new RevSlider();
        $slider_aliases = $rev_slider->getAllSliderAliases();
        if(count($slider_aliases) > 0) {
            foreach($slider_aliases as $slider_alias)
            {
                $field['choices'][$slider_alias] = $slider_alias;
            }
        } else {
            $field['choices'] = array( 'none' => 'No sliders exist. You must create one first.' );
        }
    } else {
        $field['choices'] = array( 'none' => 'Slider Revolution plugin was not found.' );
    }
    return $field;
}
//Only place these options on a specific select field with the alias "rev_slider"
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=rev_slider', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

Answer (score 0):

From Slider Revolution V6 the method "getAllSliderAliases" is not available anymore. 
New Code is :

**functions.php**

```
function my_acf_load_field($field)
{
    if (class_exists('RevSlider')) {
        $rev_slider = new RevSlider();
        $slider_aliases = $rev_slider->get_sliders();
        if (count($slider_aliases) > 0) {
            foreach ($slider_aliases as $slider_alias) {
                $field['choices'][$slider_alias->alias] = $slider_alias->alias;
            }
        } else {
            $field['choices'] = array('none' => 'No sliders exist. You must create one first.');
        }
    } else {
        $field['choices'] = array('none' => 'Slider Revolution plugin was not found.');
    }
    return $field;
}
//Only place these options on a specific select field with the alias "rev_slider"
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=rev_slider', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

**page.php**

```
$slider_alias = get_field('rev_slider');
if(!empty($slider_alias)) {
    echo do_shortcode(sprintf('[rev_slider alias="%s"]', $slider_alias));
}
```